# Getting the value of a variable after POST request

Tags: angular, typescript

There is an authorization form:

```
<form (submit)="login($event)">
    <input class="form-control" name="PromoCode" placeholder="enter promo">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary" value="login">
</form>
```

And there is a method `login`:

```
isExist : boolean = false;

...

login(e){
    var promo = e.target.elements[0].value;

    this.http.get('http://localhost:49296/api/Buyers/GetBuyer?promo=' + promo).subscribe((exist : boolean) => this.isExist = exist);

    console.log(this.isExist);
    if(this.isExist == true){
      this.router.navigate(['books']);
    }
  }
```

`localhost` is my Web API project. I check requests in Fiddler and Web API give me correct value. But when I click on login, `isExist` change only before second click. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the navigation logic to the subscribe method. The `http.get` returns a observable. That means it is **asynchronus**. So you have to move all the to the subcribe method.

```
login(e){
  var promo = e.target.elements[0].value;

  this.http.get('http://localhost:49296/api/Buyers/GetBuyer?promo=' + promo).subscribe((exist : boolean) => {

  this.isExist = exist
  console.log(this.isExist);
  if(this.isExist == true){
      this.router.navigate(['books']);
  }
  });
}
```

Comment: If this soution solves your problem please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, I just waiting for a timer. "You can accept an answer in 3 minutes"

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks @dmepty

Comment: You can simplify this answer, and also is a very bad practise to execute logic in a service